# Search for filename on Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Im creating a website where it is possible to uploade an excel file end extract data from it. In my code i uploade the excel file to the application on the server in an **Uploade** folder and extract data from it.

I am renaming the filename to a string with date and time so i delete files that is not matching the string i get from `DateTime.Now` since i dont wanna fill my server with excel files.

So i want to check for existing files in the **Uploade** folder on my server, and if there is older excel files i want to delete them.

How do i get the folder content from my server ?

My code:

```
protected void uploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        string fileuploaded = Server.MapPath("Upload") + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "excel" + Path.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName);
        fileUpload.SaveAs(fileuploaded);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) method for this:

```
string folder = Server.MapPath("Upload");
foreach (var filePath in Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*excel*"), SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
    if ((DateTime.Now - fi.CreationTime).TotalDays > 30)
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

You also can parse the creation date from the filename using [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee1y0t7.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
string folder = Server.MapPath("Upload");
foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(folder))
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(item);
    DateTime creationDate = fi.CreationTime;
    //TODO: check creation date and delete files you want...

}
```